# Initialize a class variables address to NULL in C++?

Tags: c++, class

Lets assume that i have a class as shown below:

```
  class CBase
  {
      public:
         CBase(void){};
         ~CBase(void){};
         Sigintgen m_oSignals;// This is another class variable which i have not defined here.
   };
```

The code begins as shown below:

```
       main()
       {
           CBasec *ptr = new CBasec();
           I would want the following to happen as shown below:
           &(ptr->m_oSignals) should be equal to NULL. Can anyone please suggest me how to get this?
            &(ptr->m_oSignals) = NULL; //This was tried but compilation errors.    
       }
```

Advanced thanks for the support.

Comment: In general, it will be better if you use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `*`, it'll help you with the memory management issues (And might decrease the fear of using pointers, as I assume you have because you didn't use it for `Sigintgen m_oSignals`).

Comment: The address of a (member) variable cannot be NULL. What are you trying to accomplish by having the member variable's address equal to NULL?

Comment: @PeterG. The reason i need this for unit testing using google test framework

Answer (score 1):

You can't. An object always exists once declared.

Instead you could dynamically allocate the `Sigintgen` when needed, and have `CBase` store a pointer (which can start as `nullptr`).

Or use `std::optional`.